# More compact Solution in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I have the following code:

```
for n:1 thru 11 do for j:1 thru 21 do v[n,j]:1/sqrt(dp)* 
(sum(eigenfunctionsort[n,j]*exp(%i*2*%pi*m*x/dp),m,-10,10));
```

Where eigenfunctionsort is defined earlier,x is a variable I will integrate over later and I am summing over m.

When I print say v[1,1], I get a big long nasty equation. How can i have Maxima boil this down in to something meanigful so I can check my results.

Best,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

Try the 'trigsimp' function or maybe map(trigsimp, your_expression). Not sure it will help, but it's worth a try. Also look at 'demoivre'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your vector eigenfunctionsort or your "big long nasty equation" looks like, but I often get complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors from Maxima even when I know they should be simple and real.

For example,

```
(%i1) A : matrix([1, 4, 1], [4, 1, 9], [1, 9, 1]);
(%i2) eigenvalues(A);
```

makes a mess. It can be simplified by applying `rectform` to transform the output to Cartesian form, followed by `trigreduce` to reduce the imaginary part of the result. Finally you can convert the 
result into floating point:

```
(%i3) rectform(%)$
(%i4) trigreduce(%)$
(%i5) float(%);
```